# ASP.NET WEB API ACS oAuth 2.0 vs OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, service, asp.net-web-api

I am developing web api which will be hosted in Azure. I need to implement security to handle tokens from corporate STS server. Which would be better approach:

1. ACS oAuth 2.0
2. OWIN

Seems like OWIN comes standard with WEB API 2.0 and quite easy to implement with few nugget packages. Any one have suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft ACS can be one of the authentication/token provider.  The WebAPI can use OWIN to consume tokens from different providers, such as Facebook, Azure AD, Google, Microsoft Live, ACS etc.